# SwiftUI @State to change an Image being displayed

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a Dictionary created from reading in JSON data and I am using those Variable names to populate other Views.

SO I have
`var charFullDetail: charDetail`

This returns a number of variables, but the two I am interested in are:
charFullDetail.cardFrontImage
charFullDetail.cardBackImage

These contain Strings which equate to an Image saved in the Asset Catalog.

My View then uses those variables to display the Image

`Image(charFullDetail.cardFrontImage)`

This works fine.

What I want to be able to do is turn the Image above into something dynamic, so that either it is tapped or a button is pressed and the Image displays the opposite one.

So if .cardFrontImage is being displayed and I tap the picture I want it to replace the Image with 
`Image(charFullDetail.cardBackImage`

I cannot get the code working that does this - my thought was to make a @State variable and use that in the Image() so that if that variable gets changed the Image() would update.

But if I do
`@State var card = "charFullDetail.cardFrontImage"`

and then try to use
`Image(card)`

It is failing as it cannot find the picture, as it is using the literal String as a String rather than referring to the value of that variable - if that makes sense.

Basically how can I replace using the reference charFullDetail.cardFrontImage with a stateful variable, but get it to still reference the value and not see it as String "charFullDetail.cardFrontImage"?

Answer (score 0):

Using state as a string works for me.  Are you sure there isn't something wrong with your asset? Try this Playground which uses the system images provided by SFSymbols then drop in your own images:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct V: View {
  @State var imageName = "star"

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image(systemName: self.imageName)
      Button("tap me") {
        self.imageName = self.imageName == "star" ? "star.fill" : "star"
      }
    }
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(UIHostingController(rootView: V()))
```

Comment: My issue is that I am using a Value from another struct which holds the String i want to pass into the Image() to display.

Comment: So when i call
Image(self.charFullDetailA.cardFrontImage) // that is actual an array key with a value of say AgathaV2.jpg

Comment: If i try to create a state var of type sring and assign that the string var test = self.charFullDetailA.cardFrontImage
and then try to do Image(test) rather than fetch the value from the dictionary it is trying to actually load the image called self.charFullDetailA.carfFrontImage - which of course is not an image loaded in assets.

Comment: You mean you have a UIImage and not a string? Use the other initializer `Image(uiImage: myImage)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269665-init